# jQuery: Variable points to live DOM, not copy of DOM on IE only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a DIV that contains an unordered list. I want to make a copy of this, reformat it a bit, then re-insert it back into the DOM. This works fine, execpt on IE (tested in 8 and 9 so far) where it seems that the copy of the elements seem to be live, instead of a copy.

Here's what happens:

```
var target = $('.cities').eq(0) //grab my list

var $bigList = $(target).find('li')  // grab all the list items

alert($bigList.eq(0).html()) // this displays the first list item, no problem

$(target).html(emptyList) // I put in a bunch of placeholder HTML

alert($bigList.eq(0).html()) // EMPTY on IE, same as first alert() on all others
```

It seems that `$bigList` is still pointing to the DOM, instead of being copied as a value. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$(target).html(emptyList)` use `$bigList.remove();`: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/FP5kX/

**Edit:** Call *both* statements:

```
$bigList.remove();
target.html(emptyList);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/FP5kX/2/

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear "emptylist" is some placeholder HTML that I use later.

Comment: Right.  `.remove()` removes the elements from the DOM, but does not delete them.  You still have your elements.  See the jsfiddle I posted.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you. I still wonder why IE handles this differently.

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning .cities, using the clone you will get a copy of the domelement but not the actual element

```
var target = $('.cities').clone()[0];
```